# Cypher query to retrieve indexed relationships and joined nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to retrieve relationships that are not deleted, as well as their source and target nodes.

I thought it would be as easy as:

```
START relationship=relationship:relationship_auto_index(deleted="false") 
MATCH (source)-[relationship]->(target) 
RETURN relationship, source, target;
```

But this returns 9600 rows.

Whereas this:

```
START relationship = relationship:relationship_auto_index(deleted="false") 
RETURN  relationship;
```

Returns 30 rows

I was expecting a one-to-one but clearly I'm doing something incorrectly.  Can anyone tell me what?

Comment: Try distinct in your first query RETURN clause. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, this gets what I want:

```
START source=node(*) 
MATCH source-[relationship]->target 
WHERE relationship.deleted = "false" 
RETURN source, relationship, target;
```

It seems less efficient.  Any insight that anyone can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried updating to Neo4j 1.9 or 2.0-M03? This could be a bug that has been fixed after 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference in what is returned by both?

If I remember correctly you can't do a query like this in cypher, and it seems to fail for me too at least on both 1.8.2 and 1.9.

I think what you're query actually does is a full scan of all nodes, and just returns all pairs. I set up a [small sample database](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=6hdr47). If you click view results and look at the explanation plan, you'll see that it's doing something odd. You might want to raise a bug issue with Neo4j.

Try something like this:

```
START r=relationship(0) 
MATCH p=a-[r]->b 
RETURN Distinct(p)
```

Comment: Here's another example of what I'm trying to do: http://pastie.org/pastes/8015128/text.  I want to grab the source and target nodes of a particular relationship.  For some reason I get the same results twice, just in reverse order.  Is that because the relationship itself is not directed, so technically they're both related to one another?

Comment: Also, what is the point of being able to index a relationship if it's going to scan all the nodes anyway?

Comment: So, in your sample database there, could you maybe explain how I'd go about getting both 'knows' relationships along with the source and target nodes?

Comment: I agree with your comment about the relationship index. But I think that this may just be a Cypher problem. If I use the native Java API or Gremlin I can get what you want. An alternative is the use distinct on the path.